# How to add Radio Button in Symfony Form

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4

```
 //RamsurathType.php 
 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RadioType;  
 //...
 ->add('Gender',RadioType::class,array(
    'choices'=>[
        'Male'=>'Male',
        'Female'=>'Female'
    ]
 ));
```

Hi all I'm new to symfony.
 Today i created a symfony Form using php bin/console make:form . 
      After that i created a Form Type(Ramsurath Type.php) and Entity 
      with(Firstname,Lastname,Email,Gender,Phone) Text Fields except phone.
      **Output form is working (Using CRUD function)**.
     Now i want to change the Gender field in Radio button type.
    for that i changed my code in Ramsurath Type.php
    I got error while run the program.Please Help to resolve the error...
    Thanks ..

Comment: Hi, at first, be more accurately with code formatting here (read). At second, you didn't show to us a error you got. And, at last, show the full code of type file and template? thanks)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ChoiceType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) :

```
->add('Gender', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices'  => [
        'Male' => 'Male',
        'Femail' => 'Female'
    ],
]);
```

You can render it as radio button with the `expanded` option